# Getting undefined on inputs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have tours and i need to build little filter.
but on request.input am getting undefined and in final result i get all tours not filtered ones...

```
public async tourSearch({ request, response }) {
    const tourName = request.input('tourName')
    const tourLocation = request.input('tourLocation')
    const tourCategory = request.input('tourCategory')
    console.log(tourName)
    const query = Tour.query()

    if (tourName) {
      query.where('title', tourName)
    }
    if (tourLocation) {
      query.where('location', tourLocation)
    }
    if (tourCategory) {
      query.where('category', tourCategory)
    }
    if (tourName || tourLocation) {
      query.where('title', tourName).where('location', tourLocation)
    }
    if (tourName || tourCategory) {
      query.where('title', tourName).where('category', tourCategory)
    }
    if (tourLocation || tourCategory) {
      query
        .where('location', tourLocation)
        .where('category', tourCategory)
    }
    if (tourLocation || tourCategory || tourName) {
      query
        .where('location', tourLocation)
        .where('category', tourCategory)
        .where('title', tourName)
    }

    const filteredTours = await query.orderBy('createdAt', 'asc')

    return response.json(filteredTours)
  }
```

am new in node.js so i know that am doing something wrong but can't understand what am doing wrong can someone please help me with this...

Comment: What libraries do you use?

Comment: i use adonis.js

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have to use `.from()` somewhere and `.select()` or just the second one.

Comment: Yes but problem is that u have translations json field in tours and then am using computed to get this fields where i want to search and now am getting that this fields don't exists how can i filter computed fields ?

Comment: It looks like each `.where()` is creating a new object and toy probably should assign it to some variable